# Function not defined on Firefox

Tags: javascript

I'm having a problem where My function is undefined but only on firefox but on chrome it works perfectly. I have no idea why it is doing this. Could this be because firefox needs an update or something? please help.

```
 bindInfoW(marker, content, infowindow);

 function bindInfoW(marker, content, infowindow) {
     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function (){
         infowindow.setContent(content);
         infowindow.open(map, marker);
     });
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firefox is a bit severer than other browsers, and need you to define your function before calling it :

```
function bindInfoW(marker, content, infowindow)
{
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(content);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
}   

bindInfoW(marker, content, infowindow);
```

Comment: @zessx With some editing done, works fine now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because of javascript Hoisting feature. It's recommended to decalre all you need in the top of your block (function or global scope) then using it.
some example can you found [here](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html)

your function (bindInfoW) must be hoisted in javascript, but i have no idea why this will not work in FF

Answer (score 0):

call the function **after** you define it.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
 function bindInfoW(marker, content, infowindow) {
     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function (){
         infowindow.setContent(content);
         infowindow.open(map, marker);
     });
 }  
 bindInfoW(marker, content, infowindow);
```

Answer (score 0):

Firefox doesn't hoist functions in blocks.
Put your function declaration outside of if/else blocks and it should work in the original order.

More details on this problem:
http://statichtml.com/2011/spidermonkey-function-hoisting.html